# Auto Update RecyclerView without calling asynctask again and again

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

is it possible to add new element inside recyclerview list, when there is a new entry inside backend database, without refreshing whole recyclerview again and again, and  without using post handler.

Comment: You want your backend to notify your app about changes, right?

Comment: and also how can i make the use of content provider and syncAdapter to save data from recyclerview as its local storage of application.

Comment: too many questions for a single question. Find some provider/syncAdapter tutorial first.

Comment: @vladyslav- yes i want the same, i dont want to call asynctask again n again, ot it call as background which automatically reflects the entry in my recycler view.

Comment: then you can use push notifications to notify the app that the data on the backend has changed.

Comment: You have to use push notification for this. check out `https://firebase.google.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look on CursorLoaders and Implement Observer pattern on data changed or better try: [Android Architecture Components: LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)